# How to access SVN from other machines

Tags: apache2, svn

I have limited network knowledge, I followed this guide to install subversion on a ubuntu system with the latest version :

http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=195

I've restarded the apache server and the computer is hooked on the school's network. How do I figure out the svn url? I think that right now it can't map to a domain so it's using the localhost.

To make it simple, what I want to do is write the svn url on another machine to access the data of the ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1):

First, Make sure everything's working locally:
 - Open a web browser on the system where you set up subversion
 - According to the tutorial provided, your svn-repository should be available under "/svn", so goto `http://localhost/svn` and check, if you can see the repository contents or the popup asking to provide username and password
 - If you get some error you probably have done something wrong in your svn installation. In this case, please check again your tutorial (BTW, there's also an ubuntu help page for subversion: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion)

---

Second, if your can see your svn contents, you need to figure out the IP address that is given to your system:
 - Open up a terminal an run

```
ifconfig
```

- Search for an entry beginning with "eth", e.g. eth0. If your computer has more than one network card, you might find more entries here. I'll come back to that later
 - Look for an entry called "**inet addr**" and take the numbers that are directly displayed after, e.g. something like 192.168.1.15. That's the IP address of your computer in your school's network.
 - That's already enough for a first try, so open a web browser on another computer and point it to `http://[the ip address you just figured out]/svn`
For the sample IP address I used above, this would be `http://192.168.1.15/svn`

---

Remarks:
 - IP address may change, depending how your schools network is configured. So try to get the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of your svn server. This should not change. (It's just the same as on the internet, e.g. instead of typing one of google's IP addresses, it's easier to type google.com). To find out your FQDN, type

`nslookup the ip address you just figured out`

on any computer of your schools network
 - Look for the entry "**name =**" at the bottom. That's your FQDN! Now enter that name instead of the IP address in your browser
 - If you have more than one network card in your computer, you may find more than one eth entry (e.g. eth0 and eth1). If you can find IP addresses behind the "**inet addr**" both entries, the easiest way would probably be to try all of them the way I described!
 - If you experiencing difficulties or problems when trying to get the IP address or the FQDN, or if you got your IP but you're not able to connect to the subversion server from another machine, it's also a good idea to talk to a system administrator at your school. I'm sure, they'll be able to help you with that!

Answer (score -1):

http://www.james-bennet.com/svn.htm

I did this myself and documented it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.